# How to segregate and display the data

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am actually working on Android Studio( developing an app) wherein I use bluetooth to receive some data from the bluetooth module, this data is stored in a ListAdapter and displayed in my mobile when I connect with the bluetooth module.
I get the data as shown,

23//Temp value

74// Humidity value

24

75

23

78

25

82

23

65 so on..

I need to either separate them individually or read them alternatively so that I should be able to plot a graph of the received values for the temp and the humidity readings.
Please Help, looking forward to your replies

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that you are receiving one each time you can just keep the even indexes for temperature and the odd one for humidity

```
if (index % 2 == 0){
// Treat it as Temp :: temperatureArray.add(reading[index])
} else {
// Treat it as Hum
}
```

If this is not enough you should investigate how to get additional information from the lower layer or if you have an attribute to describe your reading